# How to increment something multiple times?

Tags: python, if-statement, nested, increment

So I have this body of code:

```
 def effective_rate(db : {str: {(int,int) : float}}, state : str, income : int ) -> float:
        tax = 0
        for state in db.values():
            for(lower_limit, higher_limit), tax_rate in state.items():
                if (income >= lower_limit):
                    tax = tax + (tax_rate*(higher_limit - lower_limit))
                    if (income <= higher_limit):
                        tax = tax + (tax_rate*(income-lower_limit)) 
                        return tax
```

and this is to check my code:

```
db1 = {'CT': {(      0,  12_499): .02,
                      ( 12_500,  49_999): .04, 
                      ( 50_000,    None): .06},

               'IN': {(0, None): .04},

               'LA': {(      0,   9_999): .03,
                      ( 10_000,  12_499): .05,
                      ( 12_500,  49_999): .055,
                      ( 50_000, 299_999): .06,
                      (300_000,    None): .078},

                'MA': {(0, None): .055}}
        answer = effective_rate(db1,'CT',40_000)
```

The issues I run into is that my result should print `0.0337495`
another issue is that if a higher_limit is `None`, it raises a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'` 
How would I make it that it increments more than just once for the if statement and correctly? And how to stop the error from raising?

Comment: Why don't you just change the `None` to a very high value value like 99999999999? btw: how come "12_500" is int?

Comment: @Aryerez since 3.6 we can write integers that way: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0515/

Answer (score 0):

Use a simpler data structure. Instead of trying to define both endpoints of the tax bracket, just remember the low endpoints, since each bracket goes all the way up to the low endpoint of the next bracket. (Consider what happens if the income is $49,999 and some cents!) Then, the next problem is that the logic is wrong:

```
            if (income >= lower_limit):
                tax = tax + (tax_rate*(higher_limit - lower_limit))
                if (income <= higher_limit):
                    tax = tax + (tax_rate*(income-lower_limit)) 
                    return tax
```

If the income is within some bracket, this will first add the marginal tax for the entire bracket, in addition to the marginal tax up to the income level - only the second part is needed.

Alternately, we can simplify by storing the *differences* in tax rates for each bracket. For example, in `'LA'` we can do:

```
'LA': ((0, .03), # all income is taxed at least 3%
       (10_000, .02), # income $10k and above is taxed an additional 2%
       (12_500, .005), # and so on
       (50_000, .005),
       (300_000, .018)),
```

Notice I do not use a dict, but instead a tuple of 2-tuples. The reason is that we must be sure of the order of the brackets, and we are anyway *not using this data as a dictionary* - we don't want to solve the problem of "what is the tax rate for a given bracket?", because we will iteratively consider the brackets.

The plan is for the income above 300k to be cumulatively taxed 7.8%: 6% from all the previous steps, and then 1.8% in the last step. We just need the logic to do that:

```
    for bottom_of_bracket, tax_rate in state.items():
        if income >= bottom_of_bracket:
            tax += tax_rate * (income - bottom_of_bracket)
        # it doesn't matter if some brackets are above the income,
        # because they will fail the if condition.
    # only after considering all the brackets do we have the final tax.
```

The last consideration is that we can only return once from the function. You have written it to iterate over all of the states in the `db`, but we only care about one of them - the one named as the `state` passed to the function. Use that to look up the right state data in `db` (*now* we are using `dict`s for what they are for :) ).